How to partially use a border-radius with an actual border in a progress bar
I have multiple segments in a progress bar, in this example representing two states - achieved and planned values. The planned segment should have a border and nearing the end of the progress bar it should get the same border-radius as the background.
My problem is the following. Either the the radius is also visible within the progress bar, or I don't use a border-radius for the right corner and use overflow: hidden; to "cut off" the unwanted overflowing part of the segment but then I lose the border on the radius.
Difficult to explain, images are probably better.
This is my current output:

This is basically how I want it to look. Is it possible with a reasonably simple solution?



.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 24px;
  .segment {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
      width: 70%;
      background: blue;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      left: 70%;
      width: 28%;
      background: lightblue;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
}
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="segment"></div>
  <div class="segment"></div>
</div>




I had a similar question asked here, maybe it can give you a hint.

You want the straight vertical right-side edge of the progress bar to become rounded in the "last few percent" of the wrapper element? If so, how do you want it to change, should the right edge start to bulge outwards (towards the end), should the corners soften and recede to allow the radius to form?

You could move your border to the bottom layered progress-bar and then use a clip-path on the segments. Then if you ever want to go 100% the border-radius will still be present. Using CSS variables will allow dynamic calculations provided you want to exclude the radius from the percentage.
The clip-path - inset function defines a rectangle at the specified inset distances from each side of the reference box. So if you want to take up 70% with the first segment set the right side to 30% provided your width is 100%. Then on the :last-of-type segment if you want it to stop shy of the border-radius, calc the left side to be 100% - border-radius.
I included a few examples and how the inset could be set for differing percentages.


body {
  --br: 20px;
  --height: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.calcs {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.segment {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.segment:last-of-type {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 6rem;
  color: blue;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--height);
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  .segment {
    padding-right: var(--br);
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--height);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: var(--br) 0 0 var(--br);
      width: 100%;
      clip-path: inset(0% 30% 0% 0%);
      /* inset top, right, bottom, and left */
      background: blue;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      width: 100%;
      /* make the width 100% */
      background: lightblue;
      /* inset of 40% from right with a width of 100% - half the height */
      clip-path: inset(0% 40% 0% calc(100% - var(--height)/2));
      /* inset: top, right, bottom, and left */
    }
  }
}

.progress-bar2 {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--height);
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /* place your colored border-radius here */
  .segment {
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--height);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: var(--br) 0 0 var(--br);
      width: 100%;
      clip-path: inset(0% 30% 0% 0%);
      /* inset: top, right, bottom, and left */
      background: blue;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      width: 100%;
      /* make the width 100% */
      background: lightblue;
      /* inset of 30% from right with a width of 100%  */
      clip-path: inset(0% 50% 0% 90%);
      /* inset: top, right, bottom, and left */
    }
  }
}

.progress-bar3 {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--height);
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  .segment {
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--height);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
      width: 100%;
      clip-path: inset(0% 70% 0% 0%);
      /* inset top, right, bottom, and left */
      background: blue;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      width: 100%;
      /* make the width 100% */
      background: lightblue;
      /* inset of 30% from right with a width of 100%  */
      clip-path: inset(0% 70% 0% 100%);
      /* inset top, right, bottom, and left */
      border-radius: var(--br);
      /* giving the width 100% and border radius on end means 
                                       clip-path will have a radius on the end if 100% */
    }
  }
}

.progress-bar4 {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--height);
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  .segment {
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--height);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
      width: 100%;
      clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0%);
      /* inset top, right, bottom, and left */
      background: blue;
      border-radius: var(--br);
      /* giving the width 100% and border radius on end means 
         clip-path will have a radius on the end if 100% */
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      width: 100%;
      /* make the width 100% */
      background: lightblue;
      /* inset of 30% from right with a width of 100%  */
      clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 100%);
      /* inset top, right, bottom, and left */
      border-radius: var(--br);
      /* giving the width 100% and border radius on end means 
         clip-path will have a radius on the end if 100% */
    }
  }
}
<p class="calcs"><em>last-of-type</em> inset: right - <strong>60%</strong> (:) left - 34% => <strong>calc(100% - 40px/2)</strong> = appx: 94% total</p>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="segment">60%</div>
  <div class="segment">40% - border<br>radius</div>
</div>
<p class="calcs"><em>last-of-type</em> inset: right - <strong>50%</strong> (:) left - 40% => <strong>90%</strong> total</p>
<div class="progress-bar2">
  <div class="segment">50%</div>
  <div class="segment">40%</div>
</div>
<p class="calcs"><em>last-of-type</em> inset: right - <strong>30%</strong> (:) left - 70% => <strong>100%</strong> total</p>
<div class="progress-bar3">
  <div class="segment">30%</div>
  <div class="segment">70%</div>
</div>
<p class="calcs"><em>last-of-type</em> inset: right - <strong>0%</strong> (:) left - 0% => <strong>100%</strong> total</p>
<div class="progress-bar4">
  <div class="segment">100%</div>
  <div class="segment">0</div>
</div>



EDIT: With some javascript you can calculate the distance from center of radius on both X and Y axis to get the offset amount using an arc elipsis as described in MDN for border-top-right-radius and border-top-left-radius.
By controlling your unit lengths in CSS using variables, you can set these properties after calculating the distances from the radius of your border-radius property.
Get the width of all elements and then use them to calculate the end of the segment elements in relation to the progress-bar element (left over length). Then take that number and subtract it from the border-radius amount to get an offset from the radius center. Then we use that to find the intersecting height of the y axis line from radius.
Once we have the y axis offset length and the x axis offset length, we can set the border radius ellipses using javascript to set the style of the last-of-type elements border radius' on the right side.
segment[1].style.borderTopRightRadius = `${xAxis}px ${yAxis}px`
segment[1].style.borderBottomRightRadius = `${xAxis}px ${yAxis}px`

Math.pow
Math.sqrt
I used an allowance for the border width in a switch to accommodate differing calculated percentages.


// get the progress bar element
const progressBar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');

// method to detect the line length of the intersecting y axis line
// from center traveling the offset distance along the x axis
// returns the length of the vertical line as it intersects the outer radius
function findIntersectionHeight(radius, xOffset) {
  // returns the square root of (radius to the 2nd power minus xOffset to the 2nd power)
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(xOffset, 2));
}

// loop over the progress bar elements 
// get the index for display purposes in p tag
progressBar.forEach((bar,i) => {
  // query the segment elements within each progress-bar 
  const segment = bar.querySelectorAll('.segment');
  // for display purposes only
  const percentage = document.querySelectorAll('.percentage');
  // set css variables for first-of-type and last-of-type
  // using the dataset attributes to set lengths in progress-bar
  bar.style.setProperty('--first-width', `${segment[0].dataset.width}%`);
  bar.style.setProperty('--second-width', `${segment[1].dataset.width}%`);
  // for display purposes only
  percentage[i].innerHTML = `first-of-type percentage = ${segment[0].dataset.width}% <br> last-of-type percentage = ${segment[1].dataset.width}% <br> Total percentage = ${Number(segment[0].dataset.width) + Number(segment[1].dataset.width)}%`;
  
  // get the boundingClientRect for each element
  const barRect = bar.getBoundingClientRect();
  const firstSegRect = segment[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const secondSegRect = segment[1].getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // set an allowance for a sliding percentage when inside
  // border radius, this accommodates the border width itself
  let borderAllowance = 2;
  switch ((secondSegRect.width + firstSegRect.width) / barRect.width * 100) {
    case 99:
      borderAllowance = 1;
      break;
    case 98:
      borderAllowance = 1.336;
      break;
    case 97:
      borderAllowance = 1.667;
      break;
  }

  // get the progress-bars border radius and remove px unit length and subtract border allowance
  const barRadius = getComputedStyle(bar).borderRadius.split('px')[0] - borderAllowance;
  
  // calculate the length of the parent minus the combined length of the children minus the border allowance
  const xAxisOffset = barRect.width - (secondSegRect.width + firstSegRect.width) - borderAllowance;
  
  // calculate the distance from radius center to travel on xAxis
  const xAxis = barRadius - xAxisOffset + borderAllowance;
  
  // method to get the intersecting y axis line length of the vetical offset
  // to the outside radius from the center of the x axis within the radius
  const yAxisOffset = findIntersectionHeight(barRadius, xAxis);
  
  // calculate the remaining distance left over
  const yAxis = barRadius - yAxisOffset;

  // set the border corner properties using a css variable
  segment[1].style.borderTopRightRadius = `${xAxis}px ${yAxis}px`;
  segment[1].style.borderBottomRightRadius = `${xAxis}px ${yAxis}px`;

})
.progress-bar {
  --parent-width: 400px;
  --parent-height: 40px;
  --br: calc(var(--parent-height) / 2);
  position: relative;
  height: var(--parent-height);
  width: var(--parent-width);
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the overflow of the children */  
  .segment {
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--parent-height);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: var(--br) 0 0 var(--br);
      width: var(--first-width);
      background: blue;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      left: var(--first-width);
      width: var(--second-width);
      background: lightblue;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
}
<p class="percentage"></p>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="segment" data-width="80"></div>
  <div class="segment" data-width="16"></div>
</div>
<p class="percentage"></p>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="segment" data-width="50"></div>
  <div class="segment" data-width="47"></div>
</div>
<p class="percentage"></p>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="segment" data-width="70"></div>
  <div class="segment" data-width="28"></div>
</div>
<p class="percentage"></p>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="segment" data-width="30"></div>
  <div class="segment" data-width="69"></div>
</div>




I read about a clip-path solution and I see your code, but the "lightblue" segment is completely missing and the border is around the gray background and not the "lightblue segment". It should like like the second image I posted.

@overflowed-stacker Okay, if you want the border to be around the segment:last-of-type then clip-path will not work for you as the border will also be clipped. This is why I moved the border to the progress-bar element. I showed several examples of how you could use clip-path, a couple of them included filling in the entire segment with blue. Best of luck...

@overflowed-stacker I have included a javascript option to calculate an ellipse or circular intersection for a percentage offset of the length left over from the two segments from the radius of the border-radius set in CSS. Not sure you'll find a CSS only option here.

Oh wow, thank you. That seems like it was a lot of work. That's exactly what I needed. :)

This is almost what you want:
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  
  .segment {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    &:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
      width: 70%;
      background: blue;
    }
    
    &:last-of-type {
      left: 70%;
      width: 30%;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 10px, blue 10px 11px, lightblue 11px), radial-gradient(circle at right, lightgray, white);
      border: 1px solid blue;
      border-radius: 0 24px 24px 0;
    }
  }
}

Setting border-right: none doesn't quite get the last part.
Hope this helps!

That's the closest so far, thank you. I try to work out a solution, so the outer border is not shown.

To create a really simple CSS progress-bar, use a single DIV element with a linear-gradient background-image.
Pass the percentage value using CSS Custom Properties (Variables) like i.e:
--percent:80; or just --p:80;


.progress-bar {
  --p: 0;
  margin: 0.5em;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, blue calc(var(--p)*1%), lightblue calc(var(--p)*1%));
}
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:80;"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:20;"></div>



If you need the value visible inside the progress-bar, use a ::before or ::after pseudo-element:


.progress-bar {
  --p: 0; 
  margin: 0.5em;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, blue calc(var(--p)*1%), lightblue calc(var(--p)*1%));
  overflow: hidden;
  
  &::after {
    counter-reset: p var(--p);
    content: counter(p) "%";
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: max(0rem, calc(var(--p)*1% - 2rem));
  }
}
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:80"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:20"></div>



If you need multiple segments, use multiple --p* properties


.progress-bar {
  --p: 0; 
  margin: 0.5em;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,
    blue      calc(var(--p1)*1%),
    lightblue calc(var(--p1)*1%),
    lightblue calc(var(--p2)*1%),
    lightgray calc(var(--p2)*1%)
  );
}
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p1:50; --p2:80;"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p1:20; --p2:90;"></div>




Thanks for your answer. However, the border is around the gray background and not part of the "lightblue" segment.  The problem is the last few % of the bar, where the border should have the border-radius up until the point the bar is filled, as shown in the second image.

@overflowed-stacker oh, I get it now after your Q update. OK, in that case the above will not suit the exact needs. Secondly, design-wise, the proposed progress-bar design is odd at best, I would rather use a simpler, visually and UI/UX nicer solution over a 1px border that rounds at a specific narrow % with no actual purpose/meaning.
